# Setting up puzzles for a parallel sudoku solver

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, sudoku

I am trying to implement a parallel sudoku solver by apportioning the problems between cores where a simple backtracking algorithm is employed. I want the jobs to be distributed such that given a sudoku puzzle

```
+---+---+---+
|4..|...|8.5|
|.3.|...|...|
|...|7..|...|
+---+---+---+
|...|...|...|
```

and number of available threads is 6 the appropriate apportioning should be:

```
1.               2.               3.               4.               5.               6.
+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+    +---+---+---+    +---+---+---+    +---+---+---+    +---+---+---+
|412|...|8.5|    |416|...|8.5|    |41.|...|8.5|    |46.|...|8.5|    |47.|...|8.5|    |49.|...|8.5|
|.3.|...|...|    |.3.|...|...|    |.3.|...|...|    |.3.|...|...|    |.3.|...|...|    |.3.|...|...|
|...|7..|...|    |...|7..|...|    |...|7..|...|    |...|7..|...|    |...|7..|...|    |...|7..|...|
+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+    +---+---+---+    +---+---+---+    +---+---+---+    +---+---+---+
|...|...|...|    |...|...|...|    |...|...|...|    |...|...|...|    |...|...|...|    |...|...|...|
```

For the initial puzzle state I have a list of available empty cells. I would like to traverse the empty cells (each with a list of candidates) in the desired fashion illustrated above. Unfortunately, I have been struggling with making an efficient algorithm to achieve such a traversal.

[image]

Do you have any ideas or recommendations on what to look at?

Answer (score 1):

Each cell should be a single number or list (list, set, vector, bitset) of possible numbers (use variant type). For all but bitset the container already have iterators to traverse them. And for bitset you can do a simple loop over the 9 bits checking each.

For the overall guessing algorithm I would forget about backtracking. Instead do a depth first search and work stealing queues. What do I mean by that?

Each thread gets a queue of boards to solve. At the start all queues are empty and you insert the starting board into one queue. You also should have one condition variable to signal that new boards are in some queue.

Each thread removes the head of the queue, if possible.

Find the first field that isn't a solved number. Then iterate over the list of possible values to generate all boards with that field filled in. Filling in the number should remove the number from all lists of fields in the same row, column, square and fail if it causes some list to become empty (no possible solution). If any list is reduced to 1 element remember it and also fill it in. If at the end of all that you still have an unsolved board add it to the threads queue and trigger the condition variable to signal that new boards are in some queue.

If the queue if a thread is empty then first find the queue with the most entries. Remove half (or some other fraction) of it and put it in the threads queue. That's the work stealing part.

If all queues are empty wait for the condition variable to signal that new boards are in some queue. Notes: this is actually the starting place for all threads.

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, I am afraid this won't work for me, as I am using mpi library, where all processes have their own address spaces. Therefore I dont know how would I implement the queues and all the memory sharing among them.

Comment: "I am using mpi library, where all processes have their own address spaces."  Edit your question to include this constraint.  Otherwise people will do a lot of work to answer your question, only to have their answer rejected out of hand.

Comment: Seriously? You want to go fully distributed with multiple systems working over the network? A sudoku can be solved in seconds by a single core. It will be over before you have distributed all the work. May try chess or something where you can do a longer search for the best move.